# OutputSream.write is too slow

Tags: java, perl, download, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I am encountering with a senerior like this:

My project has a servlet to catch a request from perl. The request is to download a file. The request is a multipartRequest.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void tdRequest(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authenticate,
                              HttpServletResponse response,
                              HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
        {
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
            {
                ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload();
                FileItemIterator items = sfu.getItemIterator(request);
                while (items.hasNext())
                {
                    FileItemStream item = items.next();
                    if (("action").equals(item.getFieldName()))
                    {
                        InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                        String value = Streams.asString(stream);

                        if (("upload").equals(value))
                        {
                            uploadRequest(items, response);
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (("download").equals(value))
                        {
                            downloadRequest(items, response);
                            return;
                        }
```

The problem is not here, it appears on the downloadRequest() function.

```
    void downloadRequest(FileItemIterator items,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{ 
log.info("Start downloadRequest.......");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
File file = new File("D:\\clip.mp4");
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            //while ((datablock = dataOutputStreamServiceImpl.readBlock()) != null)
            byte[] outputByte = new byte[ONE_MEGABYE];
            while (fileIn.read(outputByte) != -1)
            {

                System.out.println("--------" + (i = i + 1) + "--------");
                System.out.println(new Date());
                //dataContent = datablock.getContent();
                System.out.println("Start write " + new Date());
                os.write(outputByte, 0,outputByte.length);
                System.out.println("End write " + new Date());
                //System.out.println("----------------------");
            }
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

I try to read and write blocks of 1MB from the file. However, it takes too long for downloading the whole file. ( my case is 20mins for file of 100MB)

I try to sysout and I saw a result like this:

The first few blocks can read, write data realy fast:

```
--------1--------
Mon Dec 07 16:24:20 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:24:20 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
--------2--------
Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
--------3--------
Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:24:21 ICT 2015
```

But the next block is slower than the previous

```
--------72--------
Mon Dec 07 16:29:22 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:29:22 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:29:29 ICT 2015
--------73--------
Mon Dec 07 16:29:29 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:29:29 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:29:37 ICT 2015

--------124--------
Mon Dec 07 16:38:22 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:38:22 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:38:35 ICT 2015
--------125--------
Mon Dec 07 16:38:35 ICT 2015
Start write Mon Dec 07 16:38:35 ICT 2015
End write Mon Dec 07 16:38:48 ICT 2015
```

The problem is in the os.write()
I realy cannot understand how the outputStream write, why it take such a long time like that? or I made some mistakes?

Sorry for my bad english. I realy need your support. Thank in advance!

This is the perl code from the client side

```
 # -----  get connected to download the file
        #
        $Response = $ua->request(POST $remoteHost ,
                        Content_Type          => 'form-data',
                        Authorization         => $Authorization,
                        'Proxy-Authorization' => $Proxy_Authorization ,

                        Content => [ DOS          => 1 ,
                                     action       => 'download' ,
                                     first_run    => 0 ,
                                     dl_filename  => $dl_filename ,
                                     delivery_dir => $delivery_dir ,
                                     verbose      => $Verbose ,
                                     debug        => $debug ,
                                     version      => $VERSION
                                   ]
                        );

        unless ($Response->is_success) {
                my $Msg = $Response->error_as_HTML;

                # Remove HTML tags - we're in a DOS shell!
                        $Msg =~ s/<[^>]+>//g;

                print "ERROR! SERVER RESPONSE:\n$Msg\n";
                print "$remoteHost\n\n" if $Options{'v'};
                Error "Could not connect to " . $remoteHost ;
        }

        my $Result2 = $Response->content();

        Error "Abnormal termination...\n$Result2" if $Result2 =~ /_APP_ERROR_/;

        open(F, ">$dl_filename") or Error "Could not open '$dl_filename'!";
        binmode F; # unless $dl_filename =~ /\.txt$|\.htm$/;
        print F $Result2;
        close F;
        print "received.\n";

        }
```

Comment: I would say that 1MB buffers may be too big, try something like 8K

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have tried random size of the buffer (2K, 4K, 500Kb, 1Mb, 10Mb) but the problem still the same :(

Comment: You didn't specify the response type, e.g. `video/mp4`. The default is `text/html` and that's not correct for an `.mp4` file. Probably won't affect performance, but give it a try. --- Since it starts out fast, then slows down, it's likely network congestion/throttling that's causing your issue.

Comment: @Andreas response.setContentType("video/mp4") yeah, i have tried, but like you said, it wont affect performance. About the network, now, the perl, the download file, the services, everything is on my local...

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that fileIn.read(outputByte) can read random number of bytes, not only full outputByte. You read few KB, then you store full 1MB, and very fast you are running out of space on disk. Try this, notice the "readed" parameter.

```
  void downloadRequest(FileItemIterator items,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    { 
    log.info("Start downloadRequest.......");
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    File file = new File("D:\\clip.mp4");
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                //while ((datablock = dataOutputStreamServiceImpl.readBlock()) != null)
                byte[] outputByte = new byte[ONE_MEGABYE];
                int readed =0;
                while ((readed =fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1)
                {

                    System.out.println("--------" + (i = i + 1) + "--------");
                    System.out.println(new Date());
                    //dataContent = datablock.getContent();
                    System.out.println("Start write " + new Date());
                    os.write(outputByte, 0,readed );
                    System.out.println("End write " + new Date());
                    //System.out.println("----------------------");
                }
                os.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a good point. I have fixed that but the performance still the same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is your network throghput? What is the network throughput of the receiving side?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your download performance gets slower and slower, the further you are getting into the download.  You start out at one or less seconds per block, by block 72 it is 7+ seconds per block and by block 128 it is 13 seconds per block.

There is nothing on the server side to explain this.  Rather, it has the "smell" of the client side doing something wrong.  My guess is that the client side is reading the data from the socket into an in-memory data structure, and that data structure (maybe just a `String` or `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`) is getting larger and larger.  Either the time take to expand it is getting larger, or your memory footprint is growing and the GC is taking longer and longer.  (Or both.)

If you showed us the client-side code .....

---

**UPDATE**

As I suspected, this line of code will be reading the entire content into the Perl equivalent of a string builder before turning it into a string.

```
   my $Result2 = $Response->content();
```

Depending on how it is implemented under the hood, this will lead to repeated copying of the data as the builder runs out of buffer space and needs to be expanded.  Depending on the buffer expansion strategy that Perl employs for this, it could give `O(N^2)` behavior, where `N` is the size of the file you are transferring.  (The evidence is that you are not getting `O(N)` behavior ...)

If you want a faster downloads, you need to stream the data on the client side.  Read the response content in chunks and write them to the output file. (I'm not a Perl expert, so I can't offer you code.)  This will also reduce the memory footprint on the client side ... which could be important if your file sizes increase.

Comment: I have just edit the question by adding some code from the client side. Could you take a look to it?

Comment: Thanks, i will check that